# Ubuntu 16 not recognizing my NVIDIA graphics card

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I am trying to use my NVIDIA graphics card as the main display option and not the build in intel display.

```
$ nvidia-smi
Failed to initialize NVML: Unknown Error
```

and running the `sudo lshw -C display` gives

```
 *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:e4000000-e4ffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:e0000000-e1ffffff ioport:2000(size=128) memory:e5000000-e507ffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: MGA G200e [Pilot] ServerEngines (SEP1)
       vendor: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       version: 07
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:e2000000-e2ffffff memory:e3810000-e3813fff memory:e3000000-e37fffff memory:e3800000-e380ffff
```

thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Did you install the proprietary drivers?

Comment: @Zacharee1 I installed the NVIDIA driver and CUDA toolkit (because I want to use CUDA) but the example code would not run (although it compiled). That is when I saw that `nvidia-smi` was not seeing the card.